# Files show diff in github desktop

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows, github-desktop

I was working on my project, when suddenly, github shows me that I have a difference in more than 140 files, many of which I never modified.
I started looking for the cause, and what I noticed was a warning saying "**Warning: line endings have changed from 'LF' to 'CRLF'.**"
This warning appeared in all the files that I had NOT modified.
I was looking at different places, but I can not find a solution. I need to be able to identify which files I modified and which ones I did not.

When working with laravel and vuejs, many changes could be produced by compiling it, and I could not identify them.

I am working with Windows 10, github desktop and sublimetext as editor. Apparently what could cause this error was the compilation of vuejs.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, try again in a newly cloned repo, *after* having set `git config --global core.autocrlf false`: that will avoid Git changing anything automatically.

Second, as in [this vuejs project](https://github.com/chrisvfritz/vue-enterprise-boilerplate/blob/master/.gitattributes), you could decide that all file should have `lf` end-of-line style (with [Git 2.10+](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.10.0.txt#L248)):

```
# Fix end-of-lines in Git versions older than 2.10
# https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.10.0.txt#L248
* text=auto eol=lf
```

Then adding exception for small static binary resources you might need in your repo:

```
# ===
# Binary Files (don't diff, don't fix line endings)
# ===

# Images
*.png binary
*.jpg binary
...
```